# Apply uppercase to lists not working

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, uppercase

list:

```
board = []
for i in range(0,5):
  board_list = ["o"] * 5
  board.append(board_list)
print str(board).upper()
```

---

Problem here how can I make it so that I can lower or  upper this in Python 3.x?
If I were to do the normal way without using a list or a dictionary it would be :

```
board = ("adsfdsfsd")
print board.upper()
```

So I want to know how I need to proceed in order to be able to solve this, and have the letters be showing the letter o uppercase like this:

```
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
```

instead of it lowercased like this:

```
[['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o']]
```

@Kevin: 
so the error that appears is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

@Kevin:
ideone to debug:
http://ideone.com/VFUWfs

I'm using this site between to test code:
http://labs.codecademy.com/#:workspace
since I'm doing the course over there

Comment: Is this your actual code? `{'gold' : 500]} * 5` is not valid Python.

Comment: That code won't work because you haven't indented it correctly, have a random `]` and can't `append` to or multiply a dictionary. In general, though, to do the same thing to every item in a collection, use a `for` loop or `map`.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is "when printing non-strings, how do I make them appear in all uppercase?", then the answer is "convert the non-string into a string, then use `upper`."

```
>>> d = {"Gold": 500}
>>> print str(d).upper()
{'GOLD': 500}
```

Comment: Hello I just updated my question: so that it appears correctly indented, and also it goes straight to the point of it, still I can't put my list into uppercases the letter o, not working

Comment: So `print str(board).upper()` isn't working? It works on my machine. What error are you getting?

Comment: After inputting:
    board = []

for i in range(0,5):
  
board_list = ["o"] * 5
  
board.append(board_list)

print str(board).upper()

if shows me Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: I suspect you have overwritten the built-in function `str` by doing something like `str = {}` earlier in your code.

Comment: I'm going to input on my edit of the title what I am inputting

Comment: [Here](http://ideone.com/E4DcUT) is a link to an online interpreter demonstrating that the code should work. If you can post a similar Ideone link to code that gives a `TypeError`, I would be happy to debug it :-)

Comment: ideone to debug: http://ideone.com/VFUWfs

I'm using this site between to test code: http://labs.codecademy.com/#:workspace since I'm doing the course over there

Comment: That Ideone is giving a SyntaxError because you specified Python 3 as the language, but Python 3 doesn't allow print statements without parentheses. [Here](http://ideone.com/cWbcVG) is a version that uses parentheses and works as expected. Still no `TypeError` to be seen.

Comment: Note that the Codecademy editor remembers the result of code you previously ran, as long as you don't refresh the page. It's possible that you wrote `str = {}`, ran it, deleted that line, and wrote your current code. `str` will still have the bad value, even though the code is gone.

Comment: well thanks it has been solved, I didn't know about that